# Xpath to extract article text from webpage

Tags: python, xpath, web-crawler

I'm going to do a webcrawling of the articles from this website.

This is what I have done so far:

```
# HR Version
# the entire crawling process

openfile = open("data/HR.csv", "rb")
r = csv.reader(openfile)
HR_data = []

for i in r:
    url = i[0]
    print url  # to know the status of web crawling
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = html.fromstring(r.text)
    #Inspect line with text
    #//*[@id="article-details"]
    #<section class="entry-content clearfix" itemprop="articleBody"></section>
    texts = data.xpath("//*[@id="article-details"]/p/text()") 
    raw = ''.join(str(i.encode("utf-8")) for i in texts)
    finaldata = raw.replace('\r','').replace('\n','').replace('\r','').replace('\t','')    
    HR_data.append([finaldata])

openfile.close()
```

The command in question is the following

```
texts = data.xpath("//*[@id="article-details"]/p/text()")
```

And it's from this particular webpage: http://hrmagazine.co.uk/article-details/internal-entrepreneurship-can-boost-your-business

Using Inspect Element on Firefox, I found the "text" is within this following segment, contained in the following section:

```
<article id="article-details">
#One <h2> element, followed by multiple <p> elements.
</article>
```

What's the correct XPath to extract only the paragraph text from the article?

Answer (score 0):

You almost wrote correct XPath. You need to replace `p` on `h2`

```
texts = data.xpath("//*[@id="article-details"]/h2/text()")
```